# LUA: how to find and match a specific string in a file name

Tags: lua

I have a file named medicine_NU12345.pdf. I want to extract the NU12345 from the pdf filename. How can I do this using Lua.

I am able to do a string.find('NU') but how do I include it to find the numbers. The numbers change for each file

Comment: `filename:match"NU%d+"`

Comment: Thank you Egor, I took this priniciple and matched with what Titus illustrated.. works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.match` and regex:

```
result = string.match(filename, "NU[%d]+")
```

Alternatively, use `string.find` which returns the beginning and end of your match, then take a substring:

```
start, stop = string.find(filename, "NU[%d]+")
result = string.sub(filename, start, stop)
```